# error message not enough disk space

Tags: downloads, macbook, disk, disk-usage

I have a older macbook, which is a 13 inch laptop. I was running OS X Lion and decided to erase my hard drive and start over with Ubuntu. Now when I try to download Ubuntu or other software, I get an error message that says I do not have enough free disk space to even start the download. How can this be if I just erased my hard drive? In addition to this I am not sure I erased my computer correctly. I am not computer savvy and will appreciate any insight for this problem. 
Here is the latest error message: Safari could not download the file “regservo_2.0.5.0.exe” because there is not enough free disk space.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Does it tell you where you need to free disk space?

Comment: Could you add the output of `df -h` in your question?

Comment: `regservo_2.0.5.0.exe` does not look like a OS X or Ubuntu program. Those files normally belong to Windows.

Comment: Make partition bigger, at least 30GB (recommended 100GB)  and you will not have this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

1. On a computer install Ubuntu onto a usb drive.
2. Boot onto the drive.
3. Click on install Ubuntu.
4. Continue through the installer until you get to something like this:

[image: Ubuntu Installation Type]

You want the one that says "Erase Ddisk and install Ubuntu".

1. Click install now!